# Flutter: How to write a PUT request for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3

Basically, like the question states, I have an s3 bucket and API that are working with Postman but when I try to do a put request through my flutter app, it fails with 403.

[image: Code snippet]

I've been at this all day but I'm totally lost, can anyone see something that's wrong or missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid header for x-api-key should be

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "x-api-key": "<s3 api key>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was the problem.